# How to open fragments from BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

Hello i have implemented a bottomsheetdilouge , i want that when the textview is pressed in the bottom sheet a fragment should open up please can you tell me how can i implement it and also want to addBackStack and when pressed log out i want to open a dilouge and not a fragment

****here is my code****

**Profile_Fragment.java** // where the bottomsheet is open when imageview is clicked

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    view.findViewById(R.id.snipet_profile);
    ImageView accountSettings = view.findViewById(R.id.account_Settings);
    // i open the bottom sheet when the imageview is clicked
    accountSettings.setOnClickListener(
            v -> {
                BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
                bottomSheet.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "ModalBottomSheet");
            }
    );
```

**BottomSheet.java // i didnt implement anything here**

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public BottomSheet() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_profile, container, false);
    }
}
```

**bottom_sheet_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slidedownview"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bottomsheetline"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slidedownview"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_profile"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/log_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/log_out"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where that fragment has to be added ? in the same activity, in a container or in another activity ????

Comment: the fragments is to be aded inside the profile fragment (which is the main fragment ) thanks for the reply

Comment: so when user click on a text in bottomsheet you need to add Profile fragment in Main fragment is that it

you can replace Main fragment with profile Fragment and adding main fragment to backstack

Comment: or create another container in MainFragment which can then be replaced with ProfileFragment

Comment: ok profile fragment is a main fragment and i have created Settigs_frag , EditProfile_frag and favourite_frag which should opens when there respected  text in the bottomsheet is pressed but for logout text i didnt created any fragment i want that when log out text is presed alert dilouge comes up for the confirmation ,sorry for the confusion you have

Comment: and when user is in any of these above mentioned three fragments and press back it returns to the Profile Fragment by addBackStack

Comment: you should consider using jetpack navigation components https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxJqHBhC4ARIsAChq4atyamFDfxgnStqNt7rKKNJU8632LiRhyuq7817uWCnzMzv3Qrb4uOgaAj0sEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?